# Do not load images with FFImageLoading

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

I am consuming an API in my application and I need to load images, I am doing it with FFImageLoading.
The images are in a json

I follow the steps of adding
 `FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.CachedImageRenderer.Init(true);` in MyActivity and AppDelegate

```
My class
 public partial class Article
    {
        [JsonProperty("source")]
        public Source Source { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("author")]
        public string Author { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public Uri Url { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("urlToImage")]
        public Uri UrlToImage { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("publishedAt")]
        public DateTimeOffset PublishedAt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("content")]
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
```

View

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                WidthRequest="300"
                                                HeightRequest="300"
                                                DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                                                Source = "{Binding UrlToImage}">
                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

[Result, i using a collectionvieww](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUM9o.png)

Comment: what type of data is "UrlToImage"? i'm assuming it's a ImageSource

Comment: try using a string instead of a Uri

Comment: Greetings, thanks for your help.   when i change to a string i have the following error`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot convert "" into Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource'`

Comment: That means the value of UrlToImage is ""(empty string) and you does not get the correct image url string from api.